# React-Intl and JSON - Can I use multiple keys in one string?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, internationalization, react-intl

I'd like to use React-Intl library, to i18n our app.
Probably we'll use json format from weblate, and there is a main question.
Can I use couple translation keys into one single string?

Dont get it? No problem, there is an example.

```
{
    "test1": "ABC",
    "test2": "CBA",
    "result": "test {test1} <--- (or any different notation)"
}

// The output for result should be: "test ABC"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// The output for result should be: "test ABC"
let a = {  
          "test1": "ABC", 
          "test2": "CBA",
          "result": "test : {test1}" 
        }

// get the line with the result
function takeResult(obj){
    let {test1, test2, result} = obj;
    return result;
}

// get the key that is in the result line
function takeKey(value){
    begin = value.search('{');
    end = value.search('}');
    return value.substring(begin+1, end);
}

// get the text 
function takeText(value){
    begin = value.search('"');
    end = value.search('{');
    return value.substring(begin+1, end);
}

//
function printTranslation(obj){
    line = takeResult(obj);
    result = takeText(line) + obj[takeKey(line)];  // use the key to access the right value
    console.log(result);
    return result; 
}

printTranslation(a);
```

Comment: This solution works only in this specific case.
I mean, lets change the order of words in result, like:

"result": "{test1}  ABC" - and output is incorrect.

Lets add another "variable" to the result: "result": "test {test1} {test2}"  - still failed.
I am hoping, that React-Intl has a some feature, and provide me some method to solve that problem.
Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now values are explicitly passed in via `values` prop so it is not officially supported. Feel free to create a GitHub issue and we can take a look.